# Can we set default values for TemplateData when using SendTemplatedEmailRequest in AWS Simple Email Service

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to send a templated email using AWS Simple Email Service.
I created this template

```
{
                    "templateName": "Test_Template",
                    "subjectPart": "Mail through AWS Template",
                    "textPart": "Hello!!",
                    "htmlPart": "<body style=\"margin: 0; padding: 0;\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<table align=\"center\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"600\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t    <tr>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t        <td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#78ab46\" style=\"padding: 40px 0 30px 0;\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t        </td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t    </tr>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t    <tr>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t        <td bgcolor=\"#eaeaea\" style=\"padding: 40px 30px 40px 30px;\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t            <p>Dear {{name}},</p>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t            <p>Sending Email using Spring Boot with <b>Thymeleaf template !!!</b></p>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t            <p>Thanks</p>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t        </td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t    </tr>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t    <tr>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t        <td bgcolor=\"#777777\" style=\"padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t            <p>{{signature}}</p>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t            <p>{{location}}</p>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t        </td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t    </tr>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</table>\r\n\r\n\t\t\t\t</body>"
}
```

It has three variables: name, location, signature.

And my request contains these values, which i am sending through rest api:

```
{
    "from" : "xyz@xyz.com",
    "to" : "pqr@pqr.com",
    "subject" : "Test mail through AWS template",
    "templateMail" : {
                    "templateName": "Test_Template",
                    "templateData" : "{\"signature\":\"Swagger\",\"name\":\"Mac\"}",
                    "defaultTemplateData" : "{\"signature\":\"DefaultSig\",\"name\":\"DefaultName\",\"location\":\"DefaultLoc\"}"
    }
}
```

Here I am providing only 2 values in templatedData field, instead of required 3 variables.

When I send the mail it does not show any error, **mail is not sent** and api shows success.

My question: is there a way we can set default values in our template? or can we pass default values to SendTemplatedEmailRequest, which will set the passed values in place of the variables?